# How to check how many virtual processors a Windows Server 2003 (D13) VM on Azure is using?

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, azure

When we say a Azure D13 instance has 8 cores, it refers to virtual processors, right?

I have uploaded a Windows Server 2003 virtual hard disk (VHD) & created a  D13 virtual machine based on that image. (I understand Windows Server 2003 is not supported on Azure but it is needed for testing)

According to this [Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn792027.aspx) on supported Windows Guest Operating Systems for Hyper-V, a Windows Server 2003 VM can support a maximum of virtual processors. However when I look at the Performance tab in the Windows Task Manager of the D13 VM, it shows 8 CPUs in use.

Is there a way to absolutely confirm that the D13 Azure VM is using all 8 cores and not just 2 cores/virtual processors as the [Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn792027.aspx) mentions?

Answer (score 3):

The article you linked says a maximum of 2 vCPUs is *supported* on Hyper-V guests running WS2003, but there are no technical reasons blocking you from using more; you are already running a completely unsupported configuration (WS2003 on Azure), so support is probably the least of your concerns.

However, in order to actually use more than 4 CPUs (regardless if physical or virtual), you need the Enterprise Edition of Windows Server 2003: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758523(v=ws.10).aspx.

Comment: Is there a way to know how many from the 8 available virtual processors the Azure D13 Windows Server 2003 VM is actually utilizing?

Comment: +1 for `...you are already running a completely unsupported configuration (WS2003 on Azure), so support is probably the least of your concerns.`.

Comment: If the VM is running the Enterprise Edition of WS2003, it's using all 8. If it's running the Standard Edition, it's using 4. If you want to see them in action, just run a load test...